# Can't use binding for ng-model-options

Tags: angularjs, angular-ngmodel

I'm trying to get `ng-model-options` to work and set it via a binding. However it doesn't seem to work when it's set in the controller.

**EG:**

This works but I don't want to pass it a string

```
input.current-page(type='text' ng-model='pageNumber.value' ng-model-options='{getterSetter: true}')
```

**My attempt:**

This returns `Cannot read property 'updateOn' of undefined`

```
link: function(scope) {
  scope.modelOpts = { getterSetter: true }
})

// view
input.current-page(type='text' ng-model='pageNumber.value' ng-model-options='modelOpts')
```

Comment: did you try using an angular expression `ng-model-options='{{modelOpts}}'` ?

Comment: It should work as longs as you have modelOpts defined. Proof here.. http://plnkr.co/edit/AMnujjxreBV0tQ0hyM8P?p=preview You must be having issue elsewhere.. In the example if you just rename the option in the view to say:- modelOpts1 (which is not defined) you will see that error, So you can take that as the clue.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Interestingly in a directive you cannot set `ng-model-options` within `link`. When used in the controller its fine.

### IE

```
// This Will Work
controller: function($scope) {
  $scope.modelOpts = {
    getterSetter: true
  }
},


// This Will Not Work
link: function(scope) {
  scope.modelOpts = {
    getterSetter: true
  }
},
```

Comment: Maybe then, but on 1.5.8 both methods will work just fine.